# Looping through array and clicking each link via CasperJS

Tags: javascript, click, casperjs

I have been using CasperJS and managed to load a page I am looking at and pull data from it. I am now looking at how to pull a list of links I want to click on and pull data from each page that opens. Here is what I have attempted so far.

```
casper.then(function(){
        var matches = this.getElementsInfo(x(".//*[@class='rows']"));
        this.click(matches[0].html;
})
```

I have tried the above code and the Elements are all returned correctly however when i try to click on them nothing happens.

Comment: are you sure you are actually clicking on a link and not on some other html element?

Comment: Yea, I have used debug in Chrome to select the link and ensure that it is indeed a link and the correct class name

Comment: Your code as it shows is not valid js - I suppose that is a copy-paste error. To be able to see what is happening you probably should include a more complete example.